# Android JSON NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json

I wrote this code in Eclipse a couple of weeks ago and it still works perfectly in Eclipse, however when I try to copy (and obviously change some parts) for Android Studio I get  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(int)' on a null object reference`.

This is the offending function:

```
public String getResultName() throws Exception {
     //This line specifically is causing the crash
    return arr.getJSONObject(0).get("name").toString();
 }
```

Setting up the array for the function call:

```
public picker(double lat, double lng, int maxPrice, double distance) throws Exception {
        responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        //Format the params
        query = String.format("type=%s&maxprice=%s&opennow=%s&key=%s&location=%s&radius=%s",
                URLEncoder.encode(type,charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(maxPrice),charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(opennow,charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(apiKey,charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(lat + "," + lng,charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(distance),charset));
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Create a connection with the URL
                    URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
                    //Set the requrest property
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
                    //Get the response
                    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
                    //Scan the response
                    Scanner responseScanner = new Scanner(response);
                    while(responseScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        responseBuilder.append(responseScanner.nextLine());
                    }
                    responseScanner.close();
                    obj = new JSONObject(responseBuilder.toString());
                    arr = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                    setRandNumber();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Anything not declared locally is a global function.
Arr is a JSON array of objects created from obj's results.
When I call the function I'm expecting to get the name of the first object in the array.

Any suggestions what's causing the null pointer exception? I've checked that all of the params being passed to picker are valid and present before I send them.

Answer (score 0):

When does getResultName() get called? 
Are you calling it just after making the picker() call ? 
If so, it maybe because the task to populate the array is still not completed, since it is on a different thread. So the array ("arr") is null at the time of calling getResultName();

Comment: That's possible, it's being called in another activity. It waits for user input but it's possible the user inputs faster than the array can fill, I'll take a look at that as a solution.

Comment: Actually I just looked at it, the call isn't made until all of the parameters are filled out by the user, however I will look at it being called before it gets the results.

Comment: okay, sure. you could debug with it i guess. one breakpoint in the thread and another in the getResultName() method